# Pulling xml data from info-path from and loading it into a mobile application

Tags: infopath, xml, mobile

Recently there has been talk about improving the purchasing process at the company I work for.  As it stands, one of the biggest limitations for the purchasing process is that the managers can not always access SharePoint to open a form and approve it.

The mindset of the IT department is to go with lazy approval to make things easier on the end user.

However, I want to take it a step further and provide the end users with a mobile application that lets them view the purchase requests that are awaiting their approvals.  At the end of the form they get a simple Approve/Reject buttons that once hit, will send their response back to SharePoint.

The first thing that I see that could throw a wrench in the works, is actually being able load the data from an info-path form into a mobile application.  I feel like this should be possible since info-path is built upon xml and the look and feel of how the data is represented would be handled by the application itself.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

My apologizes, I should have spent a few more mins researching before posting. The link to the document in an info-path library actually opens up the xml.  see the below link for more details.  This doesnt answer my question if I can load it into a mobile application, but now that I have the raw xml that shouldnt be an issue.

[social.msdn.microsoft](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/a651a9b0-14fd-4724-bcc8-3cd9ec52dcc4/accesing-form-library-and-extracting-xml-from-infopath-form?forum=sharepointcustomizationlegacy)